# Refresh token for Reddit API using Python requests

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, python-requests

I want to refresh access token but somehow my code returns empty response

```
response = requests.post(auth_url,data=refresh_data,auth=client_auth,headers=headers)
```

where `refresh_data` is

```
refresh_data = {'grant_type' : 'refresh_token',
'refresh_token' : '31763629822-aRVYmfxTAW4Sx5mihFB89sqwQno'
}
```

Here is code

```
import requests
import requests.auth
from requests import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/'

oauth_url = 'https://oauth.reddit.com/'

auth_url = 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token'

CLIENT_ID = 'api key'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'api secret'

refresh_data = {'grant_type' : 'refresh_token', 'refresh_token' : '31763629822-aRVYmfxTAW4Sx5mihFB89sqwQno'}

headers = {'User Agent' : 'Test Client v/1.0 '}


 response = requests.post(auth_url,data=refresh_data,auth=(CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET),headers=headers)

print(response.json())
```

can you help me find the error ?

Comment: Can you get more details so I can test what i thought

Comment: @kcorlidy I want to make post request to refresh token, but somehow I get either a blank response from reddit api or too many request error. I edited question with code

Comment: @kcorlidy Thanks for your time, I solved my problem. I forgot `-` in `User-Agent`. Silly me tried to solve problem for almost 6 hours. Well I guess this is what programming really is. ;)

Answer (score 0):

wrong header

```
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Test Client v/1.0 '}
```